# Default sorting in ember-models-table

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I am using ember-models-table (https://github.com/onechiporenko/ember-models-table) and I'd like to initially display the table with the records sorted by one particular column.  I can't seem to find a parameter for this in the spec.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"propertyName": "EmployeeName", "title": "EmployeeName",
"sortDirection": "asc", "sortPrecedence": 1
```

Use `sortDirection` and `sortPrecedence` to sort a particular column.